# Improper form validation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, input

I'm running into a strange issue. Here is the controller code regarding the flash:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed in!"
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Your email or password is incorrect!'
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Here is the associated view code:

```
<% if flash.now[:error] %>

        <%= label_tag :email %>
        <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: "error"%>

        <%= label_tag :password %>
        <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: "error" %>

    <% else %>

        <%= label_tag :email %>
        <%= text_field_tag :email%>

        <%= label_tag :password %>
        <%= password_field_tag :password%>

    <% end %>
```

The error class should result in the input fields turning red. However, they currently briefly flash red and then the page is rendered. What can I be doing better here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> When you need to pass an object to the current action, you use now, and your object will vanish when the current action is done.
>
> Entries set via now are accessed the same way as standard entries: flash['my-key'].

(see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now)

Try removing the '.now' in your view and instead do

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
```